# Prime numbers of the form $P^Q+R^S$

Tags: prime-numbers

Is there a prime number of the form $P^Q+R^S$ where $P,Q,R,S$ are four distinct prime numbers?

Examples: $2^3+7^5$, $2^3+5^{11}$ are not primes, $2^5+11^7$ is not a prime.

Comment: In any case, you need absolutely to use the prime $2$...

Comment: @Martigan yasman of course

Comment: 2^3+11^5=161059
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=161059

Comment: @Exodd yes that is correct,are there the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are many solutions, e.g., $2^7+3^{13}=1594451 $ is prime. Further solutions are $2^{11}+3^{29}=6863037736693$ and $2^5+3^{23}=94143178859$.